Passing on a variable created in a class to a function in that class in which the variable is defined as a global variable
Initially, before using a class, I could easily pass on a variable a to the function fit_func_simple_a_fixed() as follows (a is defined as a global variable in the function):
import pandas as pd
import math
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

time = [i for i in range(0, 9)]
cumulative_rate = [0, 0.14, 0.28, 0.36, 0.43, 0.50, 0.57, 0.60, 0.62]

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time,
                   'cumulative_rate': cumulative_rate})

def fit_func_simple_a_fixed(x, b):
    global a
    x2 = -b*x
    def fun(input):
        return(1-math.exp(input))
    x3 = np.array(list(map(fun, x2)))

    return a*x3

# Code before using a class
a = 0.8
x = np.array(df.time)
y = np.array(df.cumulative_rate)
params = curve_fit(fit_func_simple_a_fixed, x, y)
print(params)

This worked well. However, when I change the part after the # Code before ... to:
class Curve_Fit():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

        self.param = self.fit_curve()

    def fit_curve(self):
        a = 0.8
        x = np.array(self.data.time)
        y = np.array(self.data.cumulative_rate)
        params = curve_fit(fit_func_simple_a_fixed, x, y)

        return params

Curve_Fit(data=df)

Not unsurprisingly I get the error message NameError: name 'a' is not defined. I can't determine a outside the class as it is computed in the class itself for different groups. Is there a way I can make this work (maybe even via passing on a somehow to curve_fit(fit_func_simple_a_fixed, x, y))?

Define a as a parameter of the function:
def fit_func_simple_a_fixed(a, x, b):
    # remove global a
    x2 = -b * x
    ...

Instead of passing fit_func_simple_a_fixed directly to curve_fit, pass a callback that'll call fit_func_simple_a_fixed and pass a and the rest of the parameters:
curve_fit(lambda *args: fit_func_simple_a_fixed(a, *args), x, y)

There's functools.partial to simplify that syntax a bit:
curve_fit(partial(fit_func_simple_a_fixed, a), x, y)


Alternatively, make fit_func_simple_a_fixed a callable class itself which can hold onto a:
class fit_func_simple_a_fixed:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __call__(self, x, b):
        x2 = -b * x
        ...

        return self.a * x3

...

curve_fit(fit_func_simple_a_fixed(a), x, y)


thank you vm, I used the 2nd option.
